# NXCompat and DynamicBase with MPR tool

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I know that the assembly generated by C# compiler is marked as "Dynamic Base" and "NX compatible".

But running MPR tool tests against my application shows that some of the application assemblies are not marked as NX compatible and Dynamic Base compatible.

What could be a reason of this?

Comment: I had similar one. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545073/how-to-enable-aslr-feature-for-a-dll  Every one saying ASLR is enable by default. But why these monitoring tools saying it was not enabled. OK. if its enabled what to do to disable it. I want to do that from VS 2013. Here is my other question regarding that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569189/i-dont-have-the-linker-option-in-visual-studio-2013-how-to-enable-it Can you kindly look into this,