# I dont have the linker option in Visual Studio 2013 How to enable it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linker, aslr

I dont have the linker option in Visual Studio 2013
How to enable it? My project is C#. I want to enable disable ASLR, DEP features for specific DLLs

I want to see the settings related to /DYNAMICBASE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=msvc-170

I did as stated in this
[No Linker option in Visual Studio Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234899/no-linker-option-in-visual-studio-project-properties)

> Go to: Project Properties -> Configuration Manager -> General. There,
> under Project Defaults, change the Configuration Type to either
> Dynamic Library or Application. Click on Apply. Then you should see
> the Linker tab added to the menu on the left.

Comment: Pretty sure that's a C/C++ only option.

Comment: @RetiredNinja My project is using c#. This question is related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545073/how-to-enable-aslr-feature-for-a-dll?noredirect=1#comment128170548_72545073 . Since the question is opinion-based it was closed. I dont care about other DLLs. But they pointed out the DLLs from our app and saying ASLR is not enabled. ASLR is enabled by default I know. OK then if I want to disable for a specific DLL how to do that? Any clue on this highly appericiated.

Comment: You might be able to change the relevant flags in the produced DLL using the [EDITBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/xd3shwhf(v=vs.120)) tool

Comment: @KlausGütter Please explain more. How to load this tool? How to check the current statuses of ASLR and DEP

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage SO is place for practical questions. One you asking (twice already) is not - there is zero value in setting that flag for .Net code. If you really want to do that for your personal entertainment (or to entertain someone else wishes) please get yourself Win32 SDK and a good book ("Windows Internals" is always good choice for such deep things) to read and have fun in general. There also plenty of comments to get you started provided on original post... (And really demand refund for "security audit")